# blank space occurs after footer in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have a html page,it's displaying well if i put my css code in the html.for example

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">My header</div>
        <div id="content">

        Content



        </div>
        <div id="footer">My Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i put this css into external stylesheet it displaying well in first time but after i reloading the same page the empty space occurs at bottom of the page.For example
style.css

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

my.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>How To Keep Your Footer At The Bottom of The Page - CSSReset.com</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />  





</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
             header
        </div><!-- #header -->

        <div id="content">
        content
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div id="footer">
        footer
        </div><!-- #footer -->

    </div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>

</html>
```

how to correct this error?
Any help will be greately appreciated.

Comment: create a fiddle to demonstrates the problem please.

Comment: Which browser are you looking in? I suggest using something like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. Have a look at the 'layout' tab under 'inspect element'.

Comment: google chrome.it displays <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">...</html>

Comment: I see no *empty space at bottom of the page*.

Comment: @Madhesh Watch this video for a quick overview on using Chrome Developer Tools https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3HGJsNLQ1E. It will rock your world while you're developing HTML + CSS.

Comment: @MrUpsidown,empty space occurs if i reload the page.did you check after reload?

Comment: @alekjsfiddle link.http://jsfiddle.net/5orey13c/

Comment: So where is your empty space? I just made a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/xf06jsf5/ And I see no empty space.

Comment: With these code i don't see any empty space in chrome.

Comment: @MrUpsidown,@Md salahuddin,reload the page,then only you can see a blank space after footer.

Answer (score -2):

try after removing height from footer (in css).footer will take height automatically as per data.